# How to know how many items were selected in a multiSelect combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs4.2

I have a combo box with the multiSelect property and I want to know how can I know how many items were selected. I tried with:

```
combobox.store.getCount();
```

but it tells me the total of items in my combo box instead of the total of items selected by the user. Basically I want to make a condition that will trigger when the user selects more than one option in the combobox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`combo.getPicker()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-getPicker) method and `picker` have method to get selected `records`

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2f2s)**, I have created a demo using `combobox` with `multi-select`. I hope this will help you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        // The data store containing the list of states
        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
            storeId: 'states',
            data: [{
                "abbr": "AL",
                "name": "Alabama"
            }, {
                "abbr": "AK",
                "name": "Alaska"
            }, {
                "abbr": "AZ",
                "name": "Arizona"
            }]
        });

        // Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Combo Example',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'combo',
                margin: 10,
                fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
                store: 'states',
                queryMode: 'local',
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'abbr',
                multiSelect: true,
            }],
            bbar: ['->', {
                text: 'Get Selected',
                handler: function () {
                    var selectionModel = this.up('panel').down('combo').getPicker().getSelectionModel();
                    record = selectionModel.getSelection();
                    console.log(record);
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Info', 'Number of Selected record is ' + selectionModel.getCount());
                    //Ext.Msg.alert('Info', 'Selected record is <br> '+ record.map(r=>{return r.get('name')}).join('<br>'));
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: is there any way to get the number of items selected in the combobox ? I mean a number, if I select one I want to get the number 1 if I select 2 I want to get the number two and so on. Is there any way of doing that ?

Comment: yes you can do like this `combo.getPicker().getSelectionModel().getCount()` it will return selected number of items form combo.

Comment: @VictorVelasco Please see my answer I have updated and as well my [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2f2s).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution. Go to [multiselect-demo.html](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/extjs-build/examples/multiselect/multiselect-demo.html), open your browser console (F12 on Google Chrome and Firefox) and type :

```
f = Ext.getCmp("multiselect-field");
f.on("change", function () {
  console.log(this.getValue().length)
});
```

Then see what's happening when you change the selected values in the "MultiSelect Test". For more informations, see : http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect-method-getValue.